# I am working on a project in unity it is saying "The associated script cannot be loaded, please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a project in unity it is but none of  them are working everyone is saying "The associated script cannot be loaded, please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script". I have tried everything like reinstalling unity, using older version etc. What can I do?
This is one of the scripts

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseHandler: MonoBehaviour

{
    
// horizontal rotation speed
    
public float horizontalSpeed = 1f;
   
 // vertical rotation speed
   
 public float verticalSpeed = 1f;

    private float xRotation = 0.0f;

    private float yRotation = 0.0f;

    private Camera cam;

    void Start()

    {

        cam = Camera.main;

    }

    void Update()

    {

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalSpeed;

        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalSpeed;

        yRotation += mouseX;

        xRotation -= mouseY;

        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);

        cam.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, yRotation, 0.0f);

    }

}
```

Comment: Are there any compiler errors in the console?

Comment: If you aren’t getting errors, click [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/general-problem-with-scripts-the-associated-script-cannot-be-loaded.185994/) and [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/668927/the-associated-script-cannot-be-loaded-on-every-sc.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the script name doesn't the class name. Or it could be that there are complier errors but I don't see anything wrong with your script. I'm kinda new to C# and I too encountered this error and this is the only fix I know. If there are others please let me know. Hope this helps! :D